# Virtual destructor - who calls underlying free()?

Tags: c++, dll, heap-memory, virtual-destructor

I am trying to figure out whether it's safe to delete an object created in module A from module B using a virtual destructor.

When using MS C++ compiler, deleting an object having a virtual destructor results in just a single vtable call and the underlying `free()` call is performed inside it (i.e. in the same module that created the object, i.e. safe).

The questions is: is it just the current MS implementation, or is it guaranteed in some standard or document and can be safely relied on?

Here's the example of a disassembled virtual destructor call in VS2010:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test *p = new test();
008A1030  push        4  
008A1032  call        dword ptr [__imp_operator new (8A20A0h)]  
008A1038  add         esp,4  
008A103B  test        eax,eax  
008A103D  je          wmain+19h (8A1049h)  
008A103F  mov         dword ptr [eax],offset test::`vftable' (8A2100h)  
008A1045  mov         ecx,eax  
008A1047  jmp         wmain+1Bh (8A104Bh)  
008A1049  xor         ecx,ecx  
    __asm int 3;
008A104B  int         3  
    delete p;
008A104C  test        ecx,ecx  
008A104E  je          wmain+28h (8A1058h)  
008A1050  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]  
008A1052  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
008A1054  push        1  
008A1056  call        edx  
    __asm int 3;
008A1058  int         3  
    return 0;
008A1059  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to figure out whether it's safe to delete an object created in module A from module B using a virtual destructor." -- If both modules are compiled to the same ABI, then yes. The rest of your question doesn't really have much to do with this.

Comment: Same ABI - yes. Same compiler version/runtime library version - not guaranteed.

Comment: That's a different question. Mixing different runtime library versions is something the C++ standard does not specifically address, but generally speaking, that's already undefined (multiple violations of the one definition rule), so it's specific to your implementation whether it'll work and whether it's supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the caller isn't going to know the type of the object? And without knowing that type, how could the caller call `Derived::operator delete` ? Only `Derived::~Derived` can know whether `Derived::operator delete` must be called instead of the generic `::operator delete`.

Hence, we can deduce that the caller cannot call `::operator delete`.

<sub>It's unspecified whether `operator delete` later calls `free()`, but that's a detail anyway.</sub>